# CSS style one element the same as another but change one property

Tags: css

I have a the following CSS

```
input[type="text"]
{
    border: 2px solid rgb(173, 204, 204);
    height: 31px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 27px rgb(204, 204, 204) inset;
    transition:500ms all ease;
    padding:3px 3px 3px 3px;
}
```

I would like a textarea element to have the same properties as this except I don't want to specify a height element for the textarea.

Is there a way I can inherit the CSS and remove a property without having to rewrite it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply the first rule to both elements, then apply a second rule that overwrites the height property of the first rule.

```
input[type="text"], textarea
{
    border: 2px solid rgb(173, 204, 204);
    height: 31px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 27px rgb(204, 204, 204) inset;
    transition:500ms all ease;
    padding:3px 3px 3px 3px;
}
textarea {
    height: auto;
}
```